# python - iterating over a subset of a list of tuples

Tags: python

Lets say I have a **list of tuples** as follows

```
l = [(4,1), (5,1), (3,2), (7,1), (6,0)]
```

I would like to iterate over the items where the 2nd element in the tuple is 1?

I can do it using an if condition in the loop, but I was hoping there will a be amore *pythonic* way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, note to self: never use `l` (ell) as a symbol.  Likewise `O` (Oh).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[ x for x in l if x[1] == 1 ]
```

You can iterate over tuples using generator syntax as well:

```
for tup in ( x for x in l if x[1] == 1 ):
    ...
```

Comment: That genexp is far less readable than the equivalent `if` statement. This seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
ones = [(x, y) for x, y in l if y == 1]
```

or

```
ones = filter(lambda x: x[1] == 1, l)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `if`. It's clear and simple.

```
for x, y in tuples:
    if y == 1:
        do_whatever_with(x)
```

Comment: *"I can do it using an if condition in the loop, but I was hoping there will a be amore pythonic way of doing it?"*

Comment: This *is* the Pythonic way to do it. Generators and list comprehensions are fine for their intended purposes, but if you actually want to iterate over something rather than build an iterable, this is the way to go. Can you honestly claim looping over a genexp is more readable?

Answer (score 2):

Build a generator over it:

```
has_1 = (tup for tup in l if l[1] == 1)
for item in has_1:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for e in filter(l, lambda x: x[1] == 1):
    print e
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is the pythonic way to solve the problem:

```
lst = [(4,1), (5,1), (3,2), (7,1), (6,0)]
[(x, y) for x, y in lst if y == 1]
=> [(4, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1)]
```

Notice how we use tuple unpacking `x, y` to obtain each of the elements in the pair, and how the condition `if y == 1` filters out only those element with value `1` in the second element of the pair. After that, you can do anything you want with the elements found, in particular, I'm reconstructing the original pair in this part at the left: `(x, y)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to iterate, `itertools.ifilter` is a nice solution:

```
from itertools import ifilter
iter = ifilter(lambda x: x[1] == 1, l)
for item in iter:
    pass
```

Comment: This is not a great solution where the test can conveniently be captured in an `if` clause.